# error: syntax error before 'double'

Tags: c, function

```
void normalizeStepOne (double F[], double hsum, double V, double Fkjsum)
{
    int i;  
    F[i] = hsum/V;
    Fkjsum+=F[i];
return;
```

in main I try to call this function in this way:

```
normalizeStepOne (double F[0], double Csum, double VC, double Fkjsum);
```

and I got error: syntax error before 'double'

whats wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

when calling a function there is no need to specify a data type, so your call should be:

```
normalizeStepOne (F[0], Csum, VC, Fkjsum);
```

Between first parameter as from the function definition i can see is an array type but you are passing an individual array element i.e. `F[0]`, shouldn't it be `F` only

Comment: I've never understood why so many beginners seem to make this mistake, when none of them ever accidentally write something like `int a = int b * int c;`.

Answer (score 4):

You must not include type declarations at the call site. Instead it should read something like this:

```
double F[ARRAY_LEN];
double Csum;
double VC;
double Fkjsum;
/* initialize the variables */
normalizeStepOne(F, Csum, VC, Fkjsum);
```

Answer (score 3):

When you call a function, you don't give the types. Only the arguments.

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't include the data type when calling your function.

```
normalizeStepOne (F, Csum, VC, Fkjsum);
```